# Need an example of a category whose products are indexed by these sets.

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

From a Theorem that states:  For categories $J$ and $C$, if $C$ has equalizers of all pairs of arrows and "all products indexed by the sets obj($J$) and arr($J$)", then $C$ has a limit for every functor $F:J \rightarrow C.$

Can someone give a simple example of a category $J$ and $C$ such that "all products indexed by the sets obj($J$) and arr($J$)"?

I'm trying to understand what "all products indexed by ..." means and I'm not making progress.

Comment: This phrase is nonsense, at least without additional context.  Where did you encounter it?

Comment: @EricWofsey From a Theorem that states:  For categories $J$ and $C$, if $C$ has equalizers of all pairs of arrows and "all products indexed by the sets obj($J$) and arr($J$)", then $C$ has a limit for every functor $F:J \rightarrow C$.  But I'm not understanding the phrase inside the quotations.

Comment: That is a very different statement than what you wrote!  You inserted the word "are" and removed the first part of the sentence which totally changes the meaning.

Comment: My mistake, I have updated the question to better reflect what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the sentence.  The phrase "all products indexed by the sets obj($J$) and arr($J$)" is a noun phrase, not a verb phrase. In other words, the statement is

> $C$ has ... all products [that are] indexed by the sets obj($J$) and arr($J$).

That is, every collection of objects of $C$ indexed by $\mathrm{obj}(J)$ or $\mathrm{arr}(J)$ has a product.

Comment: Does the collection of objects of $C$ ALWAYS have to be indexed by obj$(J)$ or can it be subsets of obj$(J)$ too?  As in is this saying $c_i \times c_j$ is a product here?  Or ONLY $\prod_{\text{all }j \in \text{obj}(J) } c_j$ are products?

Comment: The collection must be indexed by $\mathrm{obj}(J)$ (or $\mathrm{arr}(J)$), not a subset.  Note though that once you know a terminal object exists, you can use subsets, since you can just send any unwanted indices to a terminal object.